# memory management for GCD under ARC

Tags: cocoa

currently i'm using gcd to do some job after pause(this code is running inside queue from pool):

```
            NSString *queueName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.ixc.callsfreecalls.QueueUpdateAccount%@",accountForUsing.account];
            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create([queueName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                sleep(3600);
             /// some job
```

and final release i do like:

```
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    dispatch_release(queue);

                });

            });
```

but application get a lot of memory ( i have sometime up to 210 streams to waiting), looks like this way is wrong. 
Anybody can suggest a good way to solve that issue?

Comment: It doesn't sound as if one queue object will be the cause of your memory problems. It seems more likely that something else in your code is going wrong. What do you mean with "up to 210 streams to waiting"?

Comment: thnx this was long time ago, problem is solved...